# cannot pass the editView content to a method why?

Tags: java, android

There is an `EditText` and a `Button` inside an `Activity`, After entering some text inside an `EditText` and clicking button, a method is called and passes content of `EditText` to a method like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txt_title;
    Button btn_send;
    EditText edt_notification;
    public final static String NOTIFICATION_DATA="NOTIFICATION_DATA";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_title= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        edt_notification= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_notification);
        btn_send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendNotification(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), edt_notification.getText().toString());

            }
        });


    }

    private void SendNotification(long timeInMillis, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ir.wikichera.badamchi.sendnotification.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
    android:text="Notification Text:"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/edt_notification"
    android:hint="put your text here"
    android:singleLine="false" />

<Button
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_notification"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is variable "s" is all the time giving me "Cannot Find Local Variable 's'". why? This is a simple issue but I can't understand. please explain?

[image]

Comment: try SendNotification(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), MainActivity.this.edt_notification.getText().toString());

Comment: can you put layout xml also?

Comment: need to debug the code & put xml

Comment: Interesting. Everything seems fine but.. Try to set the void as public

Comment: I run your code , it's working fine & getting toast

Comment: clean project , may be IDE refreshing issue

Comment: did you sync or clean your project?

Comment: what is your Android studio IDE version & JDK? ,  If it's 2+, then may occur

Comment: @mWhitley before sending question I did test this approach and it is working, I want to understand why I cannot pass string to a method's second parameter.

Comment: I restarted my computer let me see what is happening!

Comment: Does this work? Toast.makeText(__YourActivity.this__, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: The problem is not toast before reaching to Toast the variable s is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are using AndroidStudio that has `instant run` enabled. Try after turning it off. Because when it is enabled our code changes doesn't take place sometimes. So try after turning it off :

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and
>   uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Answer (score -1):

My Working Code :

```
public class TestAcitivity extends Activity {
TextView txt_title;
Button btn_send;
EditText edt_notification;
public final static String NOTIFICATION_DATA="NOTIFICATION_DATA";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_acitivity);

    txt_title= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    edt_notification= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_notification);
    btn_send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SendNotification(System.currentTimeMillis(), edt_notification.getText().toString());

        }
    });


}

private void SendNotification(long timeInMillis, String s) {
    txt_title.setText(s);
    Toast.makeText(TestAcitivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

this worked for me.

Comment: It's not a context reference issue

Comment: I ran your code as it is , it's working totally fine, and getting toast on screen. and yes its not context issue, context issue appears whenever we are using innerClass or Interface method.